# windbg - What does the "Commit" column of the !vad command output mean?

Tags: reverse-engineering, windbg, windows-kernel

As above, when I do a `!vad` in windbg, what do the values in under the `Commit` column mean?

```
kd> !vad
VAD           Level     Start       End Commit
ffff8908f102b0c0  4     7ffe0     7ffe0      1 Private      READONLY           
ffff8908ef465290  3     7ffe1     7ffef     -1 Private      READONLY           
ffff8908f169f100  4   fb63c20   fb63d1f      6 Private      READWRITE          
ffff8908ef4c86e0  2   fb63e00   fb63fff      3 Private      READWRITE          
ffff8908ef17e3b0  3  2e38e030  2e38e03f      0 Mapped       READWRITE          Pagefile section, shared commit 0x10
ffff8908ef592280  4  2e38e040  2e38e046      1 Private      READWRITE          
ffff8908f1873410  1  2e38e050  2e38e068      0 Mapped       READONLY           Pagefile section, shared commit 0x19
ffff8908ef106a00  3  2e38e070  2e38e073      0 Mapped       READONLY           Pagefile section, shared commit 0x4
ffff8908f19eea10  2  2e38e080  2e38e080      0 Mapped       READONLY           Pagefile section, shared commit 0x1
ffff8908f0fba340  3  2e38e090  2e38e090      1 Private      READWRITE          
ffff8908f0fdc980  0  2e38e0a0  2e3900a0      1 Private      READWRITE          
ffff8908ef215060  3  2e390130  2e39022f     17 Private      READWRITE          
ffff8908ef084860  2  2e390230  2e3902f4      0 Mapped       READONLY           \Windows\System32\locale.nls
ffff8908f14e3e90  3 7ff67f9a0 7ff67fa9f      0 Mapped       READONLY           Pagefile section, shared commit 0x5
ffff8908ef3025c0  1 7ff67faa0 7ff67fac2      0 Mapped       READONLY           Pagefile section, shared commit 0x23
ffff8908f0ef7c70  4 7ff67fe30 7ff67fe51      3 Mapped  Exe  EXECUTE_WRITECOPY  \Users\user\Desktop\test\x64\Release\test.exe
ffff8908ef6ad770  3 7ffde5240 7ffde52c7      5 Mapped  Exe  EXECUTE_WRITECOPY  \Windows\System32\apphelp.dll
ffff8908ef1bcf70  4 7ffde7470 7ffde76d5      8 Mapped  Exe  EXECUTE_WRITECOPY  \Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll
ffff8908f16717a0  2 7ffde9270 7ffde931d      5 Mapped  Exe  EXECUTE_WRITECOPY  \Windows\System32\kernel32.dll
ffff8908f0e50c30  3 7ffdea920 7ffdeaaff     12 Mapped  Exe  EXECUTE_WRITECOPY  \Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
```

Comment: I have re-posted this question to the more specific reverse engineering community (https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/21032/28026). Kindly vote to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more appropriate in reverseengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: As the owner, can't you simply delete it, instead of closing it?

Comment: Another reader may have come across this question and is interested in the answer.